# Why uniformity of $E$ is assumed inside the imagined cylinder while deriving $E$ of an infinitely large charged plate using Gauss' law?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law

[image: Using Gauss' law to derive and equation for E of an infinitely large charged plate.]

In this proof, it is first stated that the direction of $E$ is always perpendicular to the plate, and it is correct and understandable as the infiniteness of the size of the plate is taken under consideration.

But when a cylinder is considered through the plate and we proceed to apply Gauss' law on the closed surface of the cylinder, shouldn't we now state the directions of $E$ due to all the charge points on the cross sectional area of the cylinder and the plate? If we think only about the effects of the charges of this cross sectional area, it should be clear that $E$ will not be uniform, flux of the wall of the cylinder will not be zero and direction of $E$ will not be perpendicular to the caps of the cylinder.

Even after taking a finite cross sectional area and a finite closed surface (in this case a cylinder) we want to state $E$ is uniform and its direction is perpendicular to the caps of the cylinder, we must take the effects of the charges that lie outside of our cross sectional area into consideration, but why should that be?

Comment: Warm welcome to Physics stack exchange!  This is a great first question. I suggest that you learn mathjax to format out equations in later questions [refer here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: To make sure I understood your question correctly, you're saying we can only say field is uniform on the gaussian cylinder if we take in contributions of all other charges on the sheet?

Comment: Thank you for your complement, and I will try to follow your advice in my later questions.

Comment: Yes that is what I am saying, we can only say field is uniform on the gaussian cylinder if we take contributions of all other charges on the sheet.

Comment: @tom10 Yes I know Gauss' law is correct for any arbitrary surface. And you say E would be complicated if we considered with charges inside the cylinder or outside the cylinder separately, it is also my thought. But what is the reason behind simplifying it and why does it work?

Comment: @tom10 thank you for trying, I appreciate it, but it doesn't help sorry.

Comment: OK. I'm removing my comments and down voting, mostly because you don't want to clarify the question. Eg, you state, "If we think only about the effects of the charges of this cross sectional area, it should be clear that  will not be uniform, flux of the wall of the cylinder will not be zero and direction of  will not be perpendicular to the caps of the cylinder." This is true, but why does it matter? Since the E field from splitting the charge distribution in and out of the cylinder seems important to your reasoning, but it's not part of the standard approach, the question is unclear.

Comment: @tom10 What is the mathematical proof that supports this standard approach? That is my question. You cannot just simply say this is the conventional way, follow it. You must show some rigorous mathematical analysis that is consistent with the approach.

Comment: I feel like you don't get his question, the nature of uniform field is a result of considering all the charges. It may or may not be uniform due to charges in a small patch area. Gauss law only considers field of charges inside the surface( technically it does of charge outside too but their contribution is always zero)

Comment: @AYMShahriarRahman: The proof is just the proof of gauss's law. The integral of $E$ over the surface is going to be the charge of the disk inside the cylinder. The value of the integral will be the same, regardless of whether the disk is alone or embedded in another object, say, the infinite plane. $E$ will be different depending on the embedding, but the integral will remain the same. The "standard approach" is then to find a surface that works (ie, makes the integral easy) with the $E$ field of the problem. A cylinder works well with an infinite sheet but not a  solo disk.

Comment: @AYMShahriarRahman I still am not fully convinced with the answer to the quesiton and I have written an the question in my own words with pictures [in my public chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120404/buraians-not-so-secret-hideout). I suggest t you take out what is good from what I've written and modify your question so that it gets more attention

Answer (score 0):

One of my friends just told me to imagine the radius of the cylinder to be infinitely small. In that case, direction of E on the caps will be vertical to the caps and also E will be uniform.

As for the wall of the cylinder, component of E perpendicular to the wall will be nearly zero at any point on it, so it can be avoided.

Problem with the books is that the cylinder is shown to be large enough for directions and magnitude of E to be a total mess.

Comment: Because the E field is due to uniform charge on an infinite flat plate, the field is exactly perpendicular to the plate.  So, the cylinder walls are exactly parallel to the E field and the cylinder caps will be exactly perpendicular to the E field regardless of size.